# Junit Assert condtion on XML data using XPATH

Tags: junit, mule

I have the below xml as response from one end system . I want to write Junit test case using assert condition for evaluating the element values.

xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
  <record>
    <field name="name" type="java.lang.String">whiteskylabs</field>                
  </record>
</table>
```

Is there anyway in Junit to use Xpath. If can u please help me out on it.
Regards
Vikram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a separate helper test flow for the XPath evaluation, or just plain Java XPath. See here for an example of Java XPath: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0550.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use [XMLUnit](https://www.xmlunit.org/), to perform assertions on xml documents, or use Java XPath classes (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html).
Regards.